# How to make own event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

I am making a windows forms project in C#, in which I made a class `LabelX` which inherits `System.Windows.Forms.Label`, then added a property `Mass` of float type

Now, my question is how can I handle, when value of `Mass` is changed.

**e.g.:**
 When user enter value `zero` or `less than zero`
 I want to fire a message that **"Mass can't be zero or negative"**

Comment: Are you wanting to throw an Exception? You would not want to register for an event to determine failure.

Comment: i want to fire event like text_change in Label

Comment: Right but if I am the consumer, I should not have to register for a changed event to determine failure when setting a property. You should throw an exception in the setter of the property...new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Value must be greater then zero") for instance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am interpreting this correctly, there are two parts to this. First, you need to detect invalid values and throw exceptions. Second, you need to raise an event when the property changes. This can be achieved as follows.

```
private float mass;
public float Mass
{
    get
    {
        return this.mass;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value <= 0.0F)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Mass cannot be zero or negative.");
        }

        if (this.mass != value)
        {
            this.mass = value;
            OnMassChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

public event EventHandler MassChanged;

protected virtual void OnMassChanged(EventArgs args)
{
    var handler = this.MassChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, args);
    }
}
```

To show a message if an invalid entry is made, you should put a `try` \ `catch` block around the call to set `Mass` and catch the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: The logic in your if block is backwards. I think you want IF( value <= 0.0f ) throw new Exception(..);

Comment: error in line "private virtual void OnMassChanged(EventArgs args)"

Comment: @Javed: Sorry! Put `private` instead of `protected`. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
// Created an empty form with a LabelX control on it.
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Added this event from the property manager.
    private void labelX1_MassChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var label = (LabelX)sender;

        if (label.Mass <= 0.0)
            MessageBox.Show("Mass is less than or equal to 0");
    }
}

public class LabelX : Label
{
    private float _mass;

    public float Mass
    {
        get { return _mass; }
        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_mass))
            {
                _mass = value;
                OnMassChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler MassChanged;

    protected virtual void OnMassChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MassChanged != null)
            MassChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Outside of your LabelX class, create the following class:

```
public class MassChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   public float Mass { get; private set; }

   public MassChangedEventArgs(float mass)
   {
     this.Mass = mass;
   }
}
```

Also outside of your LabelX class, create the following delegate. This will be your event handler.

```
public delegate void MassChangedEventHandler(object sender, MassChangedEventArgs e);
```

Within your LabelX class, create an event to broadcast:

```
public class LabelX
{
   public event MassChangedEventHandler MassChanged;
   //the rest of your code here...
}
```

You'll also want to create a private instance method that will fire your event.

```
public class LabelX
{
   public event MassChangedEventHandler MassChanged;

   private void OnMassChanged()
   {
       if(MassChanged!=null)
          this.MassChanged(this, new MassChangedEventArgs(this.Mass));
   }
   //the rest of your code here...
}
```

Finally, whenever your Mass property changes, call OnMassChanged. For instance:

```
public class LabelX
{
   private float mass;
   public float Mass
   {
       get
       {
         return mass;
       }
       set
       {
         mass = value;
         OnMassChanged();
       }
   }

   public event MassChangedEventHandler MassChanged;

   private void OnMassChanged()
   {
       if(MassChanged!=null)
          this.MassChanged(this, new MassChangedEventArgs(this.Mass));
   }

   //the rest of your code here...
}
```

When you want to handle that event on a per-instance basis, you just have to register a listener with the MassChanged event of your underlying object and perform whatever actions are necessary.

Comment: Why would you create a delegate for this? I only create a delegate when the `EventArgs` carries state that cannot otherwise be retrieved or I need to communicate information back to the sender. The `Mass` can be easilly retrieved using `((LabelX)sender).Mass`. Isn't this preferred?

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat. But, the reason for doing this is to capture the state of an object at the point of event invocation. With your approach, the value of the Mass property could very well change between event invocation and event handler processing, causing inconsistency in state.

Answer (score 0):

Events are a common pattern used in the framework.  The process typically involves defining a delegate to be used as the event handlers, declaring the event using the handler, defining methods to raise the event, then hooking up to the properties the logic to raise the event.

The message you describe is better done as an Exception but here's an example to define the `MassChanged` event.

```
// Define event args if you have additional
// information to pass to your event handlers
public class MassChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MassChangedEventArgs(int oldMass)
    {
        OldMass = oldMass;
    }
    public int OldMass { get; private set; }
}

public class SomeObject
{
    // There's a generic event handler delegate that can be
    // used so you only need to define the event arguments.
    public event EventHandler<MassChangedEventArgs> MassChanged;

    // Convenience method to raise the event
    protected virtual void OnMassChanged(MassChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MassChanged != null)
            MassChanged(this, e);
    }

    public int Mass
    {
        get
        {
            return mass;
        }
        set
        {
            // Your checks here
            if (value <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Mass", "Mass can't be zero or negative");
            // Should only raise the event if the new value is different
            if (value != mass)
            {
                // Change the mass
                MassChangedEventArgs e = new MassChangedEventArgs(mass);
                mass = value;
                // Raise the event
                OnMassChanged(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private int mass;
}
```

After that, it's just a matter of registering handlers to the event and going from there.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure you you would like to 'fire' an exception in your case. 
This more of a validation logic issue such AOP code contracts concept.

But if you really like to create an event for it you have to at least:
1) create an event storage variable in your label class

```
  public event EventHandler MassChanged;
```

2) in your property (note that you loose the ability to use code gen functions of c# 3 for
                     which 'auto' implement the field to store your Mass property value)

```
 public bool Mass
        {
            get { return _mass; }
            set { 
                  // check if value is invalid (0 or less) && that event subscribers exist
                  if(value<=0 && MassChanged != null) { MassChanged(this, null); }
                  else // otherwise assign ...
                  {  
                  _mass = value; 
                  }                

                }
        }
```

3) create an event handler of type `EventHandler`

Best to read the msdn article for events: [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)

Again I am pretty sure you are not handling exceptions properly in the app
if you need an event for this. I mean there is nothing wrong but events are 
usually not used as means of value validations.